# What props and interface should I use for this Typescript component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, components

I am trying to make an error catcher in Typescript, using `ErrorBoundary` component. Frankly, I don't understand, what `props` and `interface` properties I should use to achieve the same goal as represented in the task from the ZTM course, which I'm taking right now. The original task is in Javascript, however my goal is to make the same app in Typescript, without using `any` type.

There is my `render()` method with a custom `ErrorBoundary` tag, which supposedly should catch errors, when those occur in my `CardList` component. The code for `render()` is below:

```
render() {
    const { robots, searchfield } = this.state;
    const fileteredRobots = robots.filter(robot => {
        return robot.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchfield.toLowerCase())
    })
    return !robots.length ?
        <h1>Loading</h1> :
        (
            <div className='tc'>
                <h1 className='f1'>RoboFriends</h1>
                <SearchBox title='search box' searchChange={this.onSearchChange}/>
                <ErrorBoundary title='error catcher'>
                    <Scroll title='scrolling'>
                    <CardList title='list of robot cards' robots={fileteredRobots} />
                    </Scroll>
                </ErrorBoundary>
            </div>
        );
    }
```

Error, which occur in this code block, says the following:

```
Type '{ children: Element; title: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<ErrorBoundary> & Readonly<{ title: string; }>'.
Property 'children' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<ErrorBoundary> & Readonly<{ title: string; }>'.ts(2322)
```

The code for component `ErrorBoundary` from **ErrorBoundary.tsx** is below:

```
import { Component } from "react";

interface IErrorBoundaryProps {
    hasError: boolean;
    children?: JSX.Element | JSX.Element[];
}

class ErrorBoundary extends Component<{title:string}, IErrorBoundaryProps> {
    constructor(props: {title:string}) {
        super (props)
        this.state = {
            hasError: false,
        }
    }

    render () {
        if (this.state.hasError) {
            return <h1>Ooops. That is an Error</h1>
        }
        return this.state.children
    }
}

export default ErrorBoundary
```

I fixed some errors from `ErrorBoundary` component, however I still get an error above in my **App.tsx** `render()` method.

My main question is: how to fix the error, that occured in my `render()` method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of things going on here.

1. You've mixed up props and state. Your `title` and `children` are **props**; `hasError` is state. But you have `title` in one type and `hasError` and `children` in another, and you've used the type `IErrorBoundaryProps` where the **state** type argument is expected.
2. The correct type for `children` in a React component is `ReactNode`.

Here's a trimmed-down version without errors:

```
import React, { Component, ReactNode } from "react";

interface IErrorBoundaryProps {
    title: string;
    children?: ReactNode;
}

interface IErrorBoundaryState {
    hasError: boolean;
}

// This one is props −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
class ErrorBoundary extends Component<IErrorBoundaryProps, IErrorBoundaryState> {
// This one is state −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    constructor(props: { title: string }) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            hasError: false,
        };
    }

    render() {
        if (this.state.hasError) {
            return <h1>Ooops. That is an Error</h1>;
        }
        return this.props.children; // ** Use `props` here
    }
}

class Example extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <ErrorBoundary title="error catcher">
                <div>Error stuff here</div>
            </ErrorBoundary>
        );
    }
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-ABU2bgAFUpXAAAbJ4zFuC+SRIZVxJULJbB7YocD2La7cj0A5ESDHeBa7yqpnWmN2h1OrE29knFZXF5WGz2fncSTKHz5PySbgfKcx530YDjD4rYHqNh6qt8UMHo+77yh2fPDY7mOs2vCZhAA)

**Also**, note that your `ErrorBoundary` component isn't an [error boundary](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html) yet, because it doesn't implement `static getDerivedStateFromError()` or `componentDidCatch()`, but I'm guessing you were going to add that later...